# Says or Said in this context, which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, word-in-context

[image]

My answer is **said** while the solution gives **says**. No idea why it's **says**, bacause I think Kate has already said that.

Comment: both are correct, but read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses#English, **is** here was a giveaway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite understandable that you chose *said*, since Kate said it in the past. However, we often use *says* when reporting what someone has told us about a present or future situation.

> Jane says she is feeling much better today.
>
> The weather man says it's going to rain tomorrow.